# php array filtering values defined by key from multiple arrays

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

Hello I'm trying to solve the following issue. I have some code which is self explanatory but I need to add a couple of lines to it
I would like filter the lower value arrays defined by the key value (in this case [2]) via the key value [1]. So if I have 3 arrays which contain key [1] with a value 100, then the arrays should be filtered via key [2].

Example of my code so far:

```
foreach($data as $line) {
if(substr($line,0,1)=="A") {
if(!$first) {
$parts = explode(chr(9), $line);
list($num1, $num2) = explode('_', $parts[1]); //code comes first / tested and works
$parts[2] = isset($num2) ? $num2 : $parts[2]; //it replaces key[2] with _* (1,2,3)

//then this will follow
$pos = strpos($parts[1], '_');  // this will remove all _* from key [1] if they exist
if($pos !== false) $parts[1] = substr($parts[1], 0, $pos); // tested and works

//echo "<pre>"; print_r($parts); echo "</pre>";

//need code to filter the arrays defined by key [1] via key [2] here?
```

So for example if I have multiple arrays after my piece of code like this:

```
Array
(
[0] => A
[1] => 100
[2] => 1
[3] => 1184
[4] => 0
)

Array
(
[0] => A
[1] => 100
[2] => 2
[3] => 1185
[4] => 0
)

Array
(
[0] => A
[1] => 100
[2] => 3
[3] => 1186
[4] => 0
)

Array
(
[0] => A
[1] => 101
[2] => 1
[3] => 1187
[4] => 0
)

Array
(
[0] => A
[1] => 101
[2] => 2
[3] => 1188
[4] => 0
)

Array
(
[0] => A
[1] => 302
[2] => 0
[3] => 1161
[4] => 0
)
```

After some code to filter the arrays, the final example result will be:

```
Array
(
[0] => A
[1] => 100
[2] => 3
[3] => 1186
[4] => 0
)

Array
(
[0] => A
[1] => 101
[2] => 2
[3] => 1188
[4] => 0
)

Array
(
[0] => A
[1] => 302
[2] => 0
[3] => 1161
[4] => 0
)
```

Please I could do with some help on this it only needs a couple of lines, I'm not a programmer but I'd like to finish this project.

Comment: once you've filtered out the "100_", then do an array sort and return the 100_ prepended to the highest value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$part = array(); 
foreach ($parts as $key => $value) { 
if (isset($part[$value[1]])) { 
if ($parts[$part[$value[1]]][0][2] < $value[0][2]) { 
$part[$value[1]] = $key; 
} 
} else { 
$part[$value[1]] = $key;

//echo "<pre>"; print_r($part); echo "</pre>";
}
}
```

I change the answer because it was not what I'm looking for but this is.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$array = array("A", "100_1", 0, 1184, 0);
$array = array_map(
    function($str) {
        return preg_replace_callback('/([\d]+)\_([1-3])/', function($matches){ return $matches[1] + $matches[2]-1;}, $str);
    },
    $array
);

print_r($array)
```

Comment: Good answer but my code is already in a function so I was thinking natsort() would be the better option ?